# Can you view your applications SQLite database remotely?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on an android application that uses the `WebView` component for all of it's display, and uses a `JavascriptInterface` to interact with native code. My question is how can I remotely view the `SQLite` database of my android application for debugging purposes. Perhaps even run some queries on it. Compiling the application and checking different results over and over on a table that I can't even see is not only frustrating, but also highly time consuming.

Currently I'm using `chrome` and it's `chrome://inspect/#devices` features for remote debugging, which shows the application, allows you to use it from the computer, and view the JavaScript debug console. I'm curious as to what it will take to be able to get into the database for `MY APPLICATION` remotely for debugging purposes. (Even if the database is read-only, that's completely fine as long as I can execute SELECT queries on it).

Perhaps this has something to do with application permissions, or maybe I'll need to write a file-server type of back-end and push the database over the network, download it on PC and then work from there, but that won't have the updated contents of the database and spending the time on making sure the database is always up to date would be a major hassle.

Curious as to if anyone else has ever ran into this issue / solved this problem in the past.

Regards, C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get SQLite database from Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062187/get-sqlite-database-from-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

While I've never used it, Facebook's open source tool stetho ([github](https://facebook.github.io/stetho/)) seems to provide this. From the page:

[image: stetho db inspection]

> Database Inspection
>
> SQLite databases can be visualized and interactively explored with
>   full read/write capabilities.