# Android Studio - SQLiteOpenHelper issues

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following Java Class

```
package com.sjhdevelopment.shaunharrison.myejuiceapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EJuiceData.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL("create table if not exists Inventory");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion)
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Recipe ADD COLUMN NOTES TEXT");
    onCreate(database);
}

}
```

Then in my main activity I have the following;

```
public class Calculation extends AppCompatActivity {
   private MyDBHelper dbHelper;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculation);
      try {
        dbHelper = new MyDBHelper(this);
        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        showError("Error", e.getMessage());
      }
   }
```

However, when I debug the code to see if the database + tables are being created with a break point on the try and on the database.execSQL("create.... 
There debugger doesn't actually go into the MyDBHelper class to do anything, therefore I'm assuming that the database + tables aren't being created

I've looked online and it says that when a getWritableDatabase/readable is called the onCreate method should get called

Any idea's as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: leoderprofi suggestion is correct!! either [upgrade database version] or [uninstall  and then re-install the app again]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreate(...)` is only called when the database is created for the first time. If you want to change your database you have to increase `DATABASE_VERSION` then it will jump into `onUpgrade(...)`

Comment: Yes, if you want to look at your database look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21062291/4265739

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SQL is not correct onCreate. Instead of `database.execSQL("create table if not exists Inventory");` it should be

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table_name 
                  (id_column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                  , column_name TEXT);";
```

You need to manually created every table with all the corrected columns. They will be created once you call the database for the first time.

Comment: There would be a distinctive error message if the sql in oncreate is not correct.

Comment: ok so lets assume for now the tables have been created, if I was to load data from the tables I normally used `SQLiteDatabase db;` , `db = openOrCreateDatabase("EJuiceData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);` , `Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT NAME FROM Recipe", null);` However now that i'm using SQLiteHelper I imagine it's changed?

Comment: nope you still do the same as you described above. Also don't forget the end the query with `;` when you do `database.execSQL`

Comment: Sorry @Aegis I have done all that, I just cut it out so that there wouldn't be so much code in the question

I've made sure all queries end with ; 

However when I'm running the code now it's saying that the tables do not exist? is there a way to delete the database so that i can run it from fresh

Comment: You can either remove the app which will remove all the app files, clear data which removes all app files but leaves the app installed.